# correct way to display EditText

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I'm confused and frustrated that I can't get my EditText field to take up a rational amount of space in the layout without explicitly telling it how many pixels to be.

I'm *sure I'm missing something obvious, but my experience is that EditText totally ignores layout_weight and either grows/shrinks dynamically with the text that is entered into it if I give it a layout_weight of "wrap_content" or takes up most of the space in its parent layout if I give it a weight of fill_parent.

So... what is the correct path to having an EditText field that occupies some portion of its parent layout (in my case Linear, but I'm flexible) so that it can have a label next to it and look like:

```
Name: [ EDIT TEXT HERE   ]
Phone:[ EDIT TEXT HERE   ]
```

etc.

TIA

Comment: The best bet would be to specify size in dp instead of pixel, it would be the best solution for supporting multiple screens. But that being said, you say layout_weight, and I think you mean to be setting layout_width

Comment: You should actually prefer `EditText` hint instead of an additional `TextView`

Comment: @DrakeClarris, no, I meant what I said. layout_weight *should do exactly what I want but for some reason does not. I dont' want to use dp because across devices that is simply not a reliable way to have something look presentable. I want the field to take up some percentage of its parent layout (hence the weight), is this *really not possible?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a couple different things. As mentioned, you should be using dp instead of pixels for layout. Using dp allows your views to scale by the screen's physical size rather than resolution.

Here's an example of specifying the edit boxes to appear to the right of each label and take up the remainder of a the screen:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_label"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Name:" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_label"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/name_label"
        android:text="Phone:" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name_label" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/phone_label"
        android:layout_below="@id/name_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's an example of a LinearLayout where weight is used:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"> 
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:text="Name:" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"> 
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:text="Phone:" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that the LinearLayout has 7 views while the RelativeLayout accomplishes something similar with 5 views. LinearLayouts hare handy, but they're more complex. As your layouts get more complicated, they will perform worse than RelativeLayouts, especially when you nest them.

Comment: hmm... this is very odd, my whole question is predicated on the understanding (as was my experience) that setting width to 0dp and regulating the size with layout_weight didn't work for some reason, but now in my current testing, it totally does.  So... great! thanks for fixing it for me by telling it that it's *supposed to work, cause it didn't want to earlier! :)

Answer (score 1):

For each line use a horizontal `LinearLayout`.

Inside that, add a horizontal `LinearLayout` to 'wrap' the `TextView`. Give that `LinearLayout` a `layout_weight` of 20 (for example).

Use another horizontal `LinearLayout` to 'wrap' the `EditText` and set the `EditText` to `fill_parent` but give its outer `LinearLayout` a `layout_weight` of 80 (or whatever value  based on 20+80 = 100% if you see what I mean).

**EDIT:** Also if you need to have multiple lines then to simplify the overall layout file, you can define a 'single line' layout file and use it as a custom layout entry.

Comment: I thought of this approach (and yes, it does work) but then I thought... can it REALLY be this convoluted to have an EditText take up some fraction of its parent layout... but you may be right, this may be the only workable solution

Comment: I've had a lot of trouble with `EditText` similar to you and the subject of your question. This is the only way I've got it to work - there may be a better way and I agree it is convoluted but it gives me consistent results so I haven't explored further.

Answer (score 0):

//for your edittext set min width and max length

```
android:minWidth="40"
android:maxLength="30"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

so that it will be always shows minimum width and your characters wont exceed more than 30.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the `Layout`. `LinearLayout` is not the right Layout for your purposes. Have a look at `TableLayout`, which I think might fulfill your requirements. Have a look at [the TableLayout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html).

Comment: interesting approach... so what would you recommend for setting the width layout_span?

Comment: Make the whole TableLayout a width of `fill_parent` and a height of `wrap_content`. The documentation says you must not set a `layout_width` for the children of the `TableLayout`. I would probably leave everything else out :-)

Comment: right, but let's say I want the input to be 75% of the table and the label ("Name") to be 25%. Then I'd have to set the layout_span for the label to 1 and the layout_span for the input to 3, and in theory this would achieve what I'm trying to do, right?